# Using Promises with Loops and Nested Functions

Tags: javascript, rest, loops, promise, nested-loops

I am trying to use promises with loops and nested functions that are within some of those loops.  I have a series of functions that are supposed to bring back SharePoint list items from REST calls - once those are done executing, then another function gets called that uses the data that was brought back.

Since there are multiple lists, and subsequently multiple list items in each, I used a while loop to make each REST call, and from there, the data (list items) are put into objects.  Those objects gets placed into an array and that's what that second functions uses to continue on.

I'm having trouble receiving the responses from the promises.  I was thinking to have multiple promises that get pushed to an array, then finally use `Promise.all` to see if everything resolved before using `then`.  The problem is that all the promises stay `pending` since I'm not returning the `resolve` correctly.  Please see below.

```
    function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {
        var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

        while (itemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
                item = item.get_item('URL');
                var itemUrl = item.get_description();

                getRequestItemsFromList(itemUrl);
            });

            promises.push(promise); // all promises are present, but their status is pending
        }

        console.log(promises);

        Promise.all(promises).then(function (val) {
            console.log(val);
            execFuncs(); // function to execute once all the above are done
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Because there's a lot of functions involved, so this is the order of execution:

```
getRequestItemsFromList //gets url for each list
execCrossDomainRequest (on success call) // makes REST call to get list and its items
cleanData // trims data and puts it in objects
```

The last is where I figured I call `Promise.resolve()` since that's the end of the line.

Either way, that's not working.  I checked out other threads, but I'm trying to do this without using any libraries.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Full relevant code:

```
var promises = [];

window.requests = [];

function getRequestLists() {
    var requestsLists = hostWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Name');  // sharepoint list with all the request list urls.
    context.load(requestsLists);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View></View>');
    var items = requestsLists.getItems(camlQuery);

    context.load(items, 'Include(URL)');

    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);

    function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {
        var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

        while (itemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
                item = item.get_item('URL');
                var itemUrl = item.get_description();

                getRequestItemsFromList(itemUrl);
            });

            promises.push(promise);
        }

        console.log(promises);

        Promise.all(promises).then(function (val) {
            console.log(val);
            execFuncs(); // not shown here
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
        alert("Request to retrieve list URL items has failed. " + args.get_message());
    }
}

function getRequestItemsFromList(url) {
    var lastPos = getSubstringIndex(url, "/", 4);
    var webUrl = url.substring(0, lastPos); // truncates list url to parse out web url       

    var absListPos = getSubstringIndex(url, "AllItems.aspx", 1);
    var absListUrl = url.substring(0, absListPos); // truncates the AllItems.aspx at the end of the list url

    var relListPos = getSubstringIndex(absListUrl, "/", 3);
    var relListUrl = absListUrl.substring(relListPos, absListUrl.length); // gets the list's relative url 

    var listName = "List Name";

    console.log(webUrl);
    execCrossDomainRequest(webUrl, listName, absListUrl);
}

function execCrossDomainRequest(webUrl, listName, absListUrl) {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);

    executor.executeAsync({ // to collect the list description
        url: appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle(@name)?" +
            "@target='" + webUrl + "'&@name='" + listName + "'" +
            "&$select=Description",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: onCallSuccess,
        error: onCallFail
    });

    function onCallSuccess(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var description = json.d.Description;

        executor.executeAsync({ // to collect the list item information
            url: appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle(@name)/items?" +
                "@target='" + webUrl + "'&@name='" + listName + "'" +
                "&$top=500&$select=*," +
                "Assigned_x0020_To/Title" +
                "&$expand=Assigned_x0020_To/Id",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: onItemsCallSuccess,
            error: onItemsCallFail
        });

        function onItemsCallSuccess(data) {
            var itemsJson = JSON.parse(data.body);
            var results = itemsJson.d.results;

            cleanData(results, description, absListUrl);
        }

        function onItemsCallFail(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            console.log("Could not make list items cross domain call. " + errorMessage);
        }
    }

    function onCallFail(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not make list cross domain call. " + errorMessage);
    }
}

function cleanData(results, listDescription, absListUrl) {

    if (!results.length) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var client = listDescription;
        var id = results[i].ID;
        ...

        }

        var request = new Request(client, id, path, title, status, estimated, assignedTo, priority, description, response);

        window.requests.push(request);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: We need to know which of your function calls in your loop are async and how their calling convention works.  Also, promises do NOT have any magic powers to know when async things are done.  They only know if an async operation is done if you specifically resolve or reject the promise when the async operation is done.  Instead, promises provide all sorts of control flow and error handling tools for async operations once each promise is plumbed appropriately.  Please document what ALL the function calls in  your loop are doing, particularly the async ones.

Comment: @jfriend00  I added in the full section of involved functions.

Comment: Why are you calling `return Promise.resolve()` inside `cleanData` and what is that supposed to do ?

Comment: @DavidDomain I am trying to return the `resolve` back to the top function so the promise's status wouldn't stay at pending.  `cleanData` gets the selected properties of an item and puts them into an object.  At that point, the promise should be resolved so the rest can continue.

Comment: Your promises do not call resolve or reject which are only defined in the promise callback context. Also are your promises  sequentially dependent to one another?

Comment: @Redu No, the promises are not dependent on each other.  By your first sentence, do you mean the calling of resolve/reject isn't in the same context as the promise declaration?  True.  When I place resolve there, it ends it too early before all the nested functions gets done.  To all - I'm totally fine with overhauling this whole chunk to make my promises work, I just don't know/understand how I can I have parallel promises go off and not resolve before `cleanData` finishes for each one.

Comment: "When I place resolve there, it ends it too early before all the nested functions gets done." ... OK promises designate a job to be completed in the future. If you have an order of jobs (nested functions as you say) to be completed within the same asynchronous timeline but before the promises that we are discussing (which means your promises are depending to their return value) then you should assign another promise(s) before them and chain your array of promises to those. I guess you have to promisfy `execCrossDomainRequest` by diverting it's success to resolve and error to reject

Comment: @Redu Should I have nested promises/chain of promises then?  And at every level listed above?  Should I still use an array of promises then?

Comment: You have a train of async functions dependend one another like `getRequestItemsFromList` -> `execCrossDomainRequest` -> `onCallSuccess` -> `onItemsCallSuccess` -> `cleanData` (not to mention their failure callbacks) You need an async flow control. Normally i would advise coroutines (promises with generators) but for the time being you can simply promisfy each step and return their resolution with resolve to the next then stage in which you will handle next asyc call. And i guess you will have the same promise train per each request.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.  I'm thinking that I will rewrite this portion to basically do this: [link](https://html5hive.org/how-to-chain-javascript-promises/)?  Is that what you mean by promisfy?  Either way, thank you so much for explaining it out for me.  There's a lot going on, and I wish my code was clearer.

Comment: Yes promisfying is wrapping the async function by a promise constructor like var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(_=> resolve(42),1000)).then(doNext).then(doTheRealNext).then(doTheUltimateNext). The document you forwarded will give you the basics well. When you feel more confident with promises; if you would like to handle the async workflow "as if" sync then have a look at this brilliant source that i have seen recently https://curiosity-driven.org/promises-and-generators. Coroutines make you run your async workflow within a generator function in the sense of sync code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a promise constructor like this:

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

It implies that somewhere inside this block you are calling `resolve` and/or `reject`, to settle the promise.

But you are never doing it, leaving the created promise object in pending state forever.

See [Constructing a promise](https://www.promisejs.org/#construction).

Comment: I do though, it's not shown above since there's a lot of code, but I write `Promise.resolve()` in `cleanData` which is another function within the one posted above.  Even doing `return Promise.resolve();` isn't changing the status.  Is it because I'm pushing the promises into the array too early?

Comment: @LaLaLottie you can't use `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()` there, those are static methods, while you have a dynamic Promise, so you are supposed to call the defined `resolve(data)` and/or `reject(reason)`. See the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your promises array is not defined: do var promises = []; before your while loop.

Comment: It is in a different part of the code.  I didn't show it here.

Comment: There are many, many other things wrong besides this.  The OP appears to have a bunch of async operations in the loop, all of which need to be plumbed with promises in order to sequence things appropriately.

Comment: It was the first thing I noticed. You can however push promises in an array and call them all with .all()